# How to enable mac address filtering in Wi-Fi Access Point on android 8.1?

Tags: wi-fi

I can do this by modifying /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf directly on android 6.0.1,but android 8.1 always covers it.

Namely,can I run hostapd manually without settiings?I tried this,but looks like  the wifi device is disable:

`#hostapd -e /data/misc/wifi/entropy.bin /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf` exited with code 1,and logcat shows **"Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device"**.

How should I enable it?

Wifi is enable in settings:

`#ip link show`

```
1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: bond0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether **:8d:**:5b:**:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether **:c8:**:b0:**:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: sit0@NONE:  mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: rmnet_ipa0:  mtu 2000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
6: rmnet_data0:  mtu 1500 qdisc htb state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
7: rmnet_data1:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
and more rmnet_data...
34: wlan0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 3000
    link/ether **:03:**:c2:**:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
35: p2p0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 3000
    link/ether **:03:**:c2:**:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`$ls /sys/devices/soc/600000.qcom,pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0`

```
broken_parity_status
class
config
consistent_dma_mask_bits
device
devspec
dma_mask_bits
driver
driver_override
enable
ieee80211
iommu_group
irq
local_cpulist
local_cpus
modalias
msi_bus
net
power
remove
rescan
reset
resource
subsystem
subsystem_device
subsystem_vendor
uevent
vendor
```

Wifi is disable in settings:

`#ip link show`

```
1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: bond0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop 
    link/ether **:8d:**:5b:**:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue 
    link/ether **:c8:**:b0:**:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: sit0@NONE:  mtu 1480 qdisc noop 
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: rmnet_ipa0:  mtu 2000 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
6: rmnet_data0:  mtu 1500 qdisc htb qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
7: rmnet_data1:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
and more rmnet_data...
```

`wlan0` is missed.

`$ls /sys/devices/soc/600000.qcom,pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0`

```
broken_parity_status
class
config
consistent_dma_mask_bits
device
devspec
dma_mask_bits
driver
driver_override
enable
iommu_group
irq
local_cpulist
local_cpus
modalias
msi_bus
power
remove
rescan
reset
resource
subsystem
subsystem_device
subsystem_vendor
uevent
vendor
```

`net` and `ieee80211` are missed.

Comment: "can I run hostapd manually without settiings?" Do you mean like through an adb shell? I believe so if you are rooted. This command might start it `adb shell su -c hostapd -B /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf`

Comment: @BoLawson I tried,`#hostapd -e /data/misc/wifi/entropy.bin /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf`exited with code 1,and logcat shows "Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device".I've edited the question.